# Super.onActivityCreated and getview are not working with ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I would like to add an adFragment to my application with the following code:

```
public  class AdFragment extends ActionBarActivity {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    }

    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

The problem is that Android Studio says that

**Cannot resolve method onActivityCreated(Android.os.Bundle)** for super.OnActivityCreated... line

and

**cannot resolve method getView()** for the next line.

I have tried that if I replace the ActionBarActivity to Fragment, there are no problems but based on 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

ActionBarActivity should work.

Does anyone has any idea about the possible solution?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Post the entire class.

Comment: yea post the codes, and have you tried re-building or cleaning

Comment: Note that activities and fragments are not interchangeable. The methods that are missing are defined in `Fragment`. Does your class extend `Fragment`?

Comment: Original:
`public  class AdFragment extends ActionBarActivity {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    }

    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work inside a `Fragment`.

Any code related to the inflated layout should be in `onViewCreated`. (You want the view not the activity, correct?) `onViewCreated` is called after `onCreateView`. The `view` parameter is the one you inflated.

```
AdView mAdView;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

**Edit: In light of new events**

The following will work inside an `Activity` (or `FragmentActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`).

```
AdView mAdView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); // the layout with this id will be inflated

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.is.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    // ...
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I don't know how the ad view works. Maybe you don't have to load the ad everytime because it remembers. Try doing it like this:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: Hi Eugen,

Thanks for your reply but I still have problems. I have changed the onActivityCreated to onViewCreated as you mentioned but still having problems with the super call:
super.onViewCreated

Error messages:
Cannot resolve method onViewCreated (android.view.Viewm android.os.Bundle).

I am using ActionBarActivity not Fragment but as far as I know ActionBarActivity extends Fragment.

Thank you!

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`. Not quite the same. So the big question is: are you writing an activity or fragment?

Comment: Finally it was an activity class. Thanks for your question Eugen.